# Is it a must to complies a model before query the data using Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

If I want to perform any query, must I first comply with a model with a schema? If I want to query the database's collection without having the schema(called by the collection name), how can I do it?

It is the query example from [Mongoose document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).

```js
const Person = mongoose.model('Person', yourSchema);

// find each person with a last name matching 'Ghost', selecting the `name` and `occupation` fields
const person = await Person.findOne({ 'name.last': 'Ghost' }, 'name occupation');
```

Comment: Mongoose is an ODM - its primary purpose is to provide models / schemas to interact with the database. If you don't need models there is no room for Mongoose at the first place.

Comment: I need models in another backend that created and inserted the data, but for this application, the job is just to query the data from the database which may not have the exact schema.

Comment: Mongoose is a clientside (in sense that nodejs is a client to the database) library.  It's scoped to the application. Mongodb knows nothing about it. My previous comment still stands - if you don't need models in this application, you don't need Mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

[`Connection.prototype.collection()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#Connection.prototype.collection())

> Retrieves a raw collection instance, creating it if not cached. This method returns a thin wrapper around a MongoDB Node.js driver collection. Using a Collection bypasses Mongoose middleware, validation, and casting, letting you use MongoDB Node.js driver functionality directly.

The database already has a `chats` collection, let's find the documents from it.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { config } from '../../config';

async function main() {
  const db = mongoose.createConnection(config.MONGODB_URI);
  const collection = db.collection('chats');

  const cursor = await collection.find();
  const docs = await cursor.toArray();
  console.log('docs:', docs)

  await db.close();
}

main();
```

Logs:

```bash
docs: [
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6465d8ccf8b3b9d3c767e639"),
    users: { '6465d8ccf8b3b9d3c767e63a': [Object] },
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

package versions:

```json
"mongoose": "^7.2.1"
```